# How to convert this string so that I can access all the elements inside?

Tags: android, json, hashmap, okhttp

So in the below I have created a request and the response String looks like this:

```
{players=18.0, lobbies=[{id=1329.0, name=Desert Duel!, players=[{id=576.0, name=cipherxof, rank=0.0, host=true}, {id=596.0, name=FTP, rank=0.0, host=false}, {id=442.0, name=Keyboard+Mouse, rank=6.0, host=false}], maxPlayers=16.0, locked=false, currentGame=0.0, games=[[0.0, 17.0, 2.0]], comment=Come test this custom map!}, {id=1410.0, name=mix 24/7, players=[], maxPlayers=13.0, locked=false, currentGame=0.0, games=[[7.0, 7.0, 0.0], [3.0, 5.0, 2.0], [7.0, 2.0, 0.0], [2.0, 5.0, 2.0], [7.0, 10.0, 0.0], [4.0, 6.0, 0.0], [2.0, 3.0, 2.0], [12.0, 15.0, 2.0], [4.0, 7.0, 0.0], [7.0, 3.0, 0.0], [6.0, 10.0, 0.0], [5.0, 7.0, 0.0]], comment=EU Host. Have fun}, {id=1642.0, name=Harambe Mix, players=[{id=426.0, name=Dormant-Hero, rank=0.0, host=true}, {id=48.0, name=Solid-Freeman, rank=0.0, host=false}, {id=567.0, name=Boris, rank=0.0, host=false}, {id=740.0, name=Kojima, rank=0.0, host=false}, {id=632.0, name=Bassernic, rank=0.0, host=false}, {id=123.0, name=xXChronosXx, rank=0.0, host=false}, {id=301.0, name=dr.penguin, rank=0.0, host=false}, {id=621.0, name=EROS, rank=0.0, host=false}, {id=705.0, name=lacefrontt, rank=0.0, host=false}, {id=794.0, name=Stravaganzza, rank=0.0, host=false}, {id=58.0, name=A H M A D, rank=0.0, host=false}, {id=34.0, name=Bloody, rank=9.0, host=false}], maxPlayers=13.0, locked=false, currentGame=7.0, games=[[7.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 5.0, 0.0], [7.0, 2.0, 0.0], [5.0, 2.0, 0.0], [16.0, 10.0, 0.0], [4.0, 6.0, 0.0], [7.0, 3.0, 0.0], [2.0, 15.0, 2.0], [4.0, 7.0, 0.0], [7.0, 3.0, 0.0], [6.0, 10.0, 0.0], [5.0, 7.0, 0.0]], comment=EU Host. Have fun}, {id=1652.0, name=MIXX, players=[{id=530.0, name=Petronas, rank=0.0, host=true}, {id=553.0, name=Dormant-Hero2, rank=0.0, host=false}, {id=727.0, name=Becky, rank=0.0, host=false}], maxPlayers=12.0, locked=false, currentGame=0.0, games=[[15.0, 7.0, 0.0], [3.0, 5.0, 0.0], [5.0, 2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 7.0, 0.0], [2.0, 5.0, 2.0], [16.0, 3.0, 0.0], [3.0, 8.0, 2.0], [5.0, 10.0, 0.0], [2.0, 15.0, 2.0], [5.0, 12.0, 0.0], [3.0, 6.0, 0.0], [16.0, 2.0, 0.0], [2.0, 7.0, 0.0], [3.0, 1.0, 0.0], [5.0, 15.0, 0.0]], comment=}]}
```

I need players and most of the lobbies information. however I cant quite figure out what I need to do to this string so that I can access all of them. What can I do? Thanks!

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private void test_connect(){
        //get request
        Log.d("GetRequest","Start that GET baby");
        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        final Request request = new Request.Builder().url("api url").build();
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
                    String responseData = response.body().string();
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseData);
                    // HashMap<String, Object> mapped = new Gson().fromJson(json.getString("data"), HashMap.class);
                    final String owner = json.getString("data");
                    Log.d("ShoRequest", owner.toString());

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                // Any other exception
                Log.d("diditworkexception", String.valueOf(ex));
            }
        }

    };
        thread.start();
    }
```

Comment: Create a model similar to it and map your response to that model and from that model you can get required data

Comment: Sounds great. However I don't actually know how to do that. Create a model I mean. I'll Google what you said and see where that takes me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bro first checks your JSON response using an online JSON viewer or JSON to POJO converter if they can convert easily then go for the next step use getter or setter.

but I have checked your JSON they give many problems I have also check JSON to java but give an exception so please check first and convert time give an error then please try to understand its a JSON response problem and android cannot handle exception into JSON because want pure JSON data other wise did not work in android.

don't get me wrong I have check and its actual facts your JSON data is totally wrong

I have attached some proof of your data

http://prntscr.com/113pl40

http://prntscr.com/113plti

http://prntscr.com/113pm8e

http://prntscr.com/113pmmu

please see the screenshot and understand properly i have also attched dummy jsondata view

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments

**for reference please visit the site for conversion**

jsonSchematoPojo

jsonformmater

or android studio inbuilt plugin Dto Generator you can find any jetbrains site

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. I have not been able to continue my work on this but hope to do so soon.

Comment: I got it! Well part of it. Thank you for looking at this. Also Thanks so much for sharing that online tools. These will help me greatly in the future.